# Using longitude and latitude after getting marked on Google Map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to use the marked longitude and latitude which the user marks on the google map by pushing it into an array. Here's my code:

```
  var Drivers = [];
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
       placeMarker(event.latLng);
       var latLng = event.latLng;
       Drivers.push(latLng);
       //alert(event.latLng);
    });
```

Trying to log the array items and getting them nulls.

[image]

Comment: so, now what? it's in the array ...

Comment: event.latLng is an object! not an array

Comment: I want to loop through this array and fetch the explicit values of lat and longitude.
function getDataList(){
          for (var i = 0; i < Drivers.length; i++) {
          console.log(Drivers[i]);
          }

Comment: did you get anything from the alert

Comment: Then, how I could fetch the explicit values of longtiude and latitude from that object.

Comment: Yes, Getting from the alert something like "(24.768185139608832, 46.747201548535145)"

Comment: So what's your expected output?

Comment: I wanted to access the lng and lat. I found that solution which fullfils my needs. event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng(). 
Thank you all for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To Get value of Latitude

```
latLng.lat()
```

To Get value of Longitude

```
latLng.lng()
```